# java program giving blank output

Tags: java, long-integer

The program works fine for small numbers but as soon as i take a big number like this it doesn't work
here is my code

```
public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long no=600851475143L,i;
        int result=0;
        for(i=(no/2);i>=2;i--){
            if(no%i==0){
                if(checkPrime(i)){
                    System.out.println("Longest Prime Factor is: " + i);
                    break;
                }
            }

        }

    }
  private static boolean checkPrime(long i){
        for(long j=2L;j<=(int)Math.sqrt(i);j++){
            if(i%j==0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: errors ? output ?

Comment: From a glance it probably works, but you do realize that it will be running quite long time? In your sample looks like it gonna be several hundred billion iterations...

Comment: i waited for 5-7 minutes still no luck..just blank output

Answer (score 0):

to assign **long variable value** we **does not require** write **L** at last on value Remove **L**.

Comment: without L it gives error because it goes out of integer range

Answer (score 0):

It will take time to display the answer. Just try with small number(1000000 ) almost 10 to 15 min for above code.

Try this

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //long no=600851475143L,i;
     System.out.println(largestPrimeFactor(600851475143L));
}
public static int largestPrimeFactor(long number) {
    int i;
    for (i = 2; i <= number; i++) {
        if (number % i == 0) {
            number /= i;
            i--;
        }
    }
    return i;
}
}
```

[1]https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes